# Injectivity and localisation in Rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A, B$ be commutative rings with identity elements and let $\mathfrak{p} \subseteq B$ be a prime ideal. Let $\varphi: A \to B$ be an injective ring homomorphism.

I want to show that the induced homomorphism $\varphi_{\mathfrak{p}} : A_{\varphi^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})} \to B_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is also injective.
Moreover: Why is the induced morphism of schemes $f: \text{Spec}(B) \to \text{Spec}(A)$ dominant?

The motivation of the first question: To show this is sufficient for showing that the induced morphism of sheaves $\mathcal{O}_{\text{Spec}(A)} \to f_{*}\mathcal{O}_{\text{Spec}(B)}$ is injective.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you help me finding a counterexample for $f$ to be dominant?

Comment: I'm getting confused as to what's conjecture and what's a task you've been given. Anyway, the dominance is true. Suppose there's an open $D(g) \subseteq \operatorname{Spec} A$ that misses the image of $f$. What can you say about $g$?

Comment: As to why $f: \operatorname{Spec} B \to \operatorname{Spec} A$ is dominant, consider $s \in A$ with $f(\operatorname{Spec} B) \subseteq V(s)$. Then $\varphi(s)$ is contained in every prime ideal of $B$, hence nilpotent in $B$, hence nilpotent in $A$.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the confusion. user26857 wrote a comment with a link to the identical question and remarked that also the dominance was false. Because of that I asked for a counterexample. Meanwhile he has deleted this wrong statement. Thanks for the proof that there is no counterexample.